# Not able to run Sublime Text 3 on Windows 10 using the command "git commit" in git

Tags: git, command-line

Sublime text 3 is my default text editor "subl.

> `git commit 'C:/Program\ Files/Sublime\ Text\ 3/sublime_text.exe' -n -w -m`: `C:/Program\ Files/Sublime\ Text\ 3/sublime_text.exe`: No such file or directory error: There was a problem with the editor '`'C:/Program\ Files/Sublime\ Text\ 3/sublime_text.exe' -n -w -m`'. Please supply the message using either `-m` or `-F` option.

Comment: Where exactly is the executable sublime_text.exe on your computer?

Comment: C:/Program\ Files/Sublime\ Text\ 3/sublime_text.exe

Comment: Not everything on Windows lets you use `/` and ``\`` interchangeably. Try using ``\``.

Comment: Could you show ***exactly*** how you've configured Git to use Sublime Text? Show us the ***exact*** line in the config file.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IfLhXM4RnB4...
I did exactly as shown here, I used exactly as given

Comment: did it with sublime text 2 also, But even then it churns out the same message...

Answer (score 1):

I have just solved this problem: opening Sublime with GitBash in Windows 10 by just thinking in line with the way Sublime 2 is set up. Simply I added the following line to bashrc file:

```
alias subl="C:/Program\ Files/Sublime\ Text\ 3/sublime_text.exe"
```

Note that this will not work:

```
alias subl="C:/Program Files/Sublime Text 3/sublime_text.exe"
```

It is a cmd approach. Though I do not know why the sublime text 3 is separated by \ since the dir name is Sublime Text 3