# after using git commit its says is not recognized as an internal and external command

Tags: git, github-for-windows

I used `git init` then `git add -A` then I tried to `git commit` but there is something wrong I cant figure it out what is it? how can I overcome the problem?

This is the message I'm getting:
`$ git commit hint: Waiting for your editor to close the file... 'C:\Users\Riki'' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. error: There was a problem with the editor '"C:\Users\Riki' galeria\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin\code.cmd" --wait'. Please supply the message using either -m or -F option.`

Comment: Your git configuration is incorrect in that it doesn't properly quote the editor command you've specified. As such, when you ask git to commit without using `-m`, git wants to open your editor to prompt you for a commit message and then fails because the path to your editor wasn't properly quoted, and thus git thinks everything up to the first space is the command name, the rest are arguments. Add the correct quotes to the configuration file and it should work. The git config file uses single quotes, not double, so that is likely the reason as I see double quotes in that error message.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Not able to run Sublime Text 3 on Windows 10 using the command "git commit" in git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36555565/not-able-to-run-sublime-text-3-on-windows-10-using-the-command-git-commit-in-g)